# python-telegram-bot - How to add handler for dice

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot, dice

Any idea how to add handler for a `Dice` roll in `python-telegram-bot`. I can see the documentation available [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.dice.html). But there is no documentation on how to handle a `Dice`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `MessageHandler` with the `Filters.dice`

```py
MessageHandler(Filters.dice, handle_dice)
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.dice) you can specify which type of dice (darts, bowling, basketball) and you can also specify the value of the dice to handle.